# where is hwinterface.sys for controling LPT?

Tags: c++, parallel-port

I try to set parallel port in my win32 application.
i use `inpout32.dll` in my program.
it works in windows XP but doesn't work in windows 7.

this occurred because i have `hwinterface.sys` in windows XP but i don't have this file in windows 7.

my question is : where is `hwinterface.sys`? and how can i find it? or how can i work with LPT without using `inpout32.dll`.

these functions are in inpout32.dll:

```
hComm01 = CreateFile("\\\\.\\hwinterface", 
                             GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                             0, 
                             NULL,
                             OPEN_EXISTING, 
                             FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                             NULL);
DeviceIoControl(hComm01,
               IOCTL_WRITE_PORT_UCHAR,
               &Buffer,
               3,
               NULL,
               0,
               &BytesReturned,
               NULL);
```

Comment: IIRC inpout32.dll automatically extracts and loads its driver in kernel mode, there should be no need to have a separate .sys file; maybe you are using an older 32 bit version on a 64 bit OS? Are you sure you are using the latest version (http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/), which includes drivers for both 32 and 64 bit Windows?

Comment: thanks for reply. but my windows 7 is 32 bit and also I have installed my parallel port driver.

Comment: The parallel port driver is another thing, inpout32 has to load its own driver to act as a bridge between the privileged instructions that have to run in kernel mode and your user-mode program. Again: are sure you are using the latest version of inpout32.dll from the page I linked?

Comment: thanks Matteo. your comment help me. I had to run as admin for first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first time I should run as Administrator.

refrence:
the first time it is run, it must be elevated on Vista and later (run as Administrator).

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/

Comment: Well yes, Windows is designed to protect system stability.  In order to bypass those protections and give full hardware control to non-kernel code, you must have administrator access.